# Bundle extra sends wrong string

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm building a notification for when a user receives a friend request. The notification has an accept and decline button and depending on what the user clicks the activity started will handle the request. Anyway when a user clicks on accept the activity started should receive a request titled accept and vice versa. However for some freak reason, whether I click accept or decline, the request string returns decline. I even comment out the decline request string to on send accept or null, but it still returns decline. It's just ridiculous. Here is what I did.

```
public void newRequest(String name,String id, String relation){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
        Bundle extras= new Bundle();
        extras.putString("request", "accept");
        extras.putString("relation", relation);
        extras.putString("name", name);
        extras.putString("id", id);


        Intent in = new Intent(this, Contacts.class); 
        Bundle extra= new Bundle();
        extra.putString("request", "decline");
        extra.putString("relation", relation);
        extra.putString("name", name);
        extra.putString("id", id);

        intent.putExtras(extras);
        in.putExtras(extra);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, 0);

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(name+" sent you have received a friend request")
            .setContentText("Reflap").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fav)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(0, "Accept", pIntent)
            .addAction(0, "Decline", pIn)
            .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(5, noti);

    }
```

This is the activity that receives the intent

```
  Intent intent=getIntent();
        //userName=intent.getStringExtra("username");
        Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        ///*if(extras.getString("request")!=null){
        try{
        requester=extras.getString("request");
        senderId=extras.getString("id");
        namer=extras.getString("name");
        relation=extras.getString("relation");
        System.out.println("Starting to perform an accept with "+namer+" and user id "+senderId+" and request is "+requester);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But every time whatever button I click the string returns decline. It's really weird.

Comment: where are you starting your activity with the created intent?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The intent is triggered by an alarmservice that checks for a friend request, if there is a friend request it triggers a notification which the user can then act upon.

Comment: try passing `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to the `PendingIntent.getActivity`

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out. The problem was here

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, 0);
```

Both request code where the same. It needed to be different. This works:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, in, 0);
```

Comment: Yeah, having different extras doesn't make PendingIntents different enough from the system's perspective, so the old one gets reused. Another way to do this would be to append some unique string to the data URI.

Comment: i think without adding two different flag u can use this one
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT instead of flag in both pendingintent

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael :) .. its working fine.. PendingIntent.getActivity(context,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mIntent, 0);